# How to check if an image path is valid in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**What I want to do:**

I want to add all images within a specific folder into a List.
The number of images within may vary between 1-10, but they are all named as numbers. The current way I am doing it is by first making all 10 of them and then removing the ones that don't exist.

```
List = []
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
List.push('Folder/' + i+1 + 'jpg')
}

List = ['Folder/1.jpg', 'Folder/2.jpg', 'Folder/3.jpg'..]
```

**Note:**
I am not going to host this anywhere. This is something I am making just for me. When I want to use the site I am just gonna open the index.html from the project folder.

I did some research and this seemed to work, but only while using live server in Visual Studio. This doesn't work when simply opening the index.html file locally.

```
function checkImage(){
temp_list = []
  for(i=0; i<List.length; i++){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', List[i], false);
    http.send();

    if(http.status != 404){
      temp_list.push(List[i])
    }
  }

  List= temp_list
```

I've also tried this, but it deletes everything in the List.

```
function checkImage(){
  temp_list = []
  for(i=0; i<List.length; i++){
    checkImage2(List[i])
  }
  console.log(temp_list.length)
  List= temp_list
}

function checkImage2(path){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = temp_list.push(path)
    img.onerror = temp_list.splice(path,1)
    img.src = path
}
```

**My question:** Is there a better way to check if a file(img) exists?

Comment: I understand this script runs in your browser and you want it to access file system of the computer that runs the browser. Browsers are doing all they can to prevent this for security reasons (think viruses).

Comment: The script works with live server because you're making http requests to a local web server, checking the response http code. 404 means not found. So it's the web server that is doing the checking.

Comment: What do you want to do with the images that exist? Do you need to use HTML / browser? You could run the script from a command line, without web browser.

Comment: `img.onerror` and `img.onload` need to be set to a _function_.  `temp_list.splice(path,1)` is not a function.  It will just be ran and its return value will be set to `img.onerror`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `image.onerror` to check if image load correctly.

```js
let images = ["invalid.jpg", "invalid2.jpg", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png"]
let workedimages = images.slice()
images.forEach((item, index) => {
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = item
  img.onerror = () => workedimages.splice(workedimages.indexOf(item), 1)
  if (index == images.length - 1) {
    img.onload = () =>
      console.log(workedimages)
  }
})
```